# Adding integer values across rows in SQL

Tags: sql, rows

I am trying to add values across rows using SQL, but I keep getting an error "string matching regex" expecting. What does this mean?

I have tried the following construction:

```
SELECT (Col_1 + Col_2) AS 'new column'
FROM table;
```

They are both integer columns. I am using data on data.world, so not sure about the RDBMS. I am only sending one query at a time.

Why might this not be working for me?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

The use of single quotes for strings is not standard.  I would suggest trying a more normal identifier, such as:

```
SELECT (Col_1 + Col_2) AS new_column
FROM table;
```

If this returns a similar error, then the issue is not your query -- which is quite simple.  Assuming you are using a database that supports SQL, then I would guess that "table" is really a view and the problem is happening in the view.

Comment: Didn't you answer exactly this question yesterday? Same user?

Comment: If the problem is happening in the view, what could my work around look like?

Comment: @Willy_Golden . . . Fix the view or report the problem to whomever is responsible for the view.  It has a bug.